# How to receive attributes from users who signed in via an identity provider in AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I want to allow my users to sign in with an identify provider using AWS Cognito.

```js
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
...

Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: "Google" })};
```

This actually works fine. After a user signs in, the user gets also listed in the user pool in the AWS console with the desired attributes - hence the attribute mapping seems to work as well.

However, when `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` gets called in my frontend while a user is sign in via federation, the *returned object doesn't contain the users attributes* - this property is somehow missing.

```js
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
...
const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
const { attributes } = user;
console.log('current attributes:', attributes);
```

returns => current attributes: `undefined`

The same method does return the attributes for users who aren't using a federation service.

```js
current attributes: 
{
    email: ...
    given_name ...
}
```

How can I make Cognito return the attributes also for users which signed in via an identify provider, so that I e.g. can display the full name of the user?

Comment: Provide code examples, we need to see what you achived so far. Otherwise it's hard to help. Anyway according to your description, I think you are doing something wrong. Basically you should get all user information from `CognitroUserPool.getCurrentUser()` that's is necessary anyway to authorize the user, otherwise session object should have it somewhere.

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js#retrieve-current-session

Comment: or even `CognitroUserPool.getUserAttributes()`

Comment: you're right. the object has the attributes somewhere - I just didn't expect it the be such nested - since its mentions differently in the documentation you also linked

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the attributes deeply nested in the returned object (e.g. given_name):

```js
{
  "username": "Google_xy",
  "pool": {
    "userPoolId": ...,
    "clientId": ...,
    "client": {
      ...
    },
  
  "signInUserSession": {
    "idToken": {
      "jwtToken": ...
      "payload": {
        "at_hash": ...,
        "sub": ...,
        "cognito:groups": [
          ...
        ],
        "email_verified": ...,
        "iss": ...,
        "cognito:username": ...,
        "given_name": ...,
        "nonce": ...,
        "aud": ...,
        "identities": [
          ...
        ],...
      }
    },
    "refreshToken": {
      "token": ""
    },
    "accessToken": {
      "jwtToken": 
...
```

Comment: This isn't a solution as attributes would still be missing. If you have custom attributes you can't just pick them up inside signInUserSession.idToken.payload

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get user attributes in a flutter project by using flutter amplify package, here is how you can access all the attributes:

```
var res = await Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes();
    for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        print("${res[i].userAttributeKey} :: ${res[i].value}");
      }
```

!

Comment: This function is for iOS not for React-native. `userAttributes`  is the function you need.

https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#userattributes